# Correctly formulate if statement in switch

Tags: swift, if-statement, mathematical-expressions

This might be a very rudimentary question, but I'm playing around with if statements and the following example won't work with error "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions". Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

```
let a = 4

let b = 3

let c = 10

let d = 2


if ((sqrt((a - b)^2 + (c - d)^2)) > 100) {
              print("Yes")
        }
```

---

Edit: I understood I made a few mistakes and now got it working with:

```
var a = 4

var b = 3

var c = 10

var d = 2

var e = (a-b)

var f = (c-d)

var g = (e*e)

var h = (f*f)

var j = Double(g+h)

if (j.squareRoot() > 5) {
              print("Yes")
      }
```

Comment: `^ 2` is not "squared". https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2964513

Comment: `if (a - b) * (a - b) + (c - d) * (c - d) > 10000 {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use better types!

```swift
import simd

distance([4, 10] as SIMD2<Double>, [3, 2]) > 100
```

And if you've really got to work with those integers…

```swift
public extension SIMD where Scalar: FloatingPoint {
  init<Integer: BinaryInteger>(_ integers: Integer...) {
    self.init( integers.map(Scalar.init) )
  }
}

distance( SIMD2<Double>(a, c), .init(b, d) ) > 100
```